# Regular expressions, matching operator using a string variable in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, string-matching

I am using a `regex` but am getting some odd, unexpected "matches".  "Names" are sent to a subroutine to be compared to an array called `@ASlist`, which contains multiple rows.  The first element of each row is also a name, followed by 0 to several synonyms.  The goal is to match the incoming "name" to any row in `@ASlist` that has a matching cell.

Sample input, from which `$names` is derived for the comparison against `@ASlist`:

```
13  1   13  chr7    7   70606019    74345818    Otud7a  Klf13   E030018B13Rik   Trpm1   Mir211  Mtmr10  Fan1    Mphosph10   Mcee    Apba2   Fam189a1    Ndnl2   Tjp1    Tarsl2  Tm2d3   1810008I18Rik   Pcsk6   Snrpa1  H47 Chsy1   Lrrk1   Aldh1a3 Asb7    Lins    Lass3   Adamts17
```

Sample lines from @ASlist:

```
HSPA5   BIP FLJ26106    GRP78   MIF2        
NDUFA5  B13 CI-13KD-B   DKFZp781K1356   FLJ12147    NUFM    UQOR13
ACAN    AGC1    AGCAN   CSPG1   CSPGCP  MSK16   SEDK
```

The code:

```
my ($name) = @_;  ## this comes in from another loop elsewhere in code I did not include
chomp $name;

my @collectmatches = (); ## container to collect matches

foreach my $ASline ( @ASlist ){

    my @synonyms = split("\t", $ASline );

    for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar @synonyms; $i++ ){
         chomp $synonyms[ $i ];
         #print "COMPARE $name TO $synonyms[ $i ]\n";

         if ( $name =~m/$synonyms[$i]/ ){
              print "\tname $name from block matches\n\t$synonyms[0]\n\tvia $synonyms[$i] from AS list\n";
              push ( @collectmatches, $synonyms[0], $synonyms[$i] ); 
          }
         else {
              # print "$name does not match $synonyms[$i]\n"; 
         }
    }
}
```

The script is working but also reports weird matches.  Such as, when `$name` is "E030018B13Rik" it matches "NDUFA5" when it occurs in `@ASlist`.   These two should not be matched up.

If I change the regex from `~m/$synonyms[$i]/` to `~m/^$synonyms[$i]$/`, the "weird" matches go away, BUT the script misses the vast majority of matches.

Comment: Your input data looks like fixed-width data.  Is that the case? If so, a regex may not even be the optimal tool for unpacking the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NDUFA5` record contains `B13` as a pattern, which will match `E030018<B13>Rik`.

If you want to be more literal, then add boundary conditions to your regular expression `/\b...\b/`.  Also should probably escape regular expression special characters using [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

```
if ( $name =~ m/\b\Q$synonyms[$i]\E\b/ ) {
```

Or if you want to test straight equality, then just use [`eq`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eq.html)

```
if ( $name eq $synonyms[$i] ) {
```

Comment: I don't understand, how exactly do those two actually match?

Comment: Because `B13` is inside the string `E030018B13Rik`.  If you don't want it to perform like that, you'll need to add boundary conditions to the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Another, more Perlish way to test for string equality is to use a hash.

You don't show any real test data, but this short Perl program builds a hash from your array `@ASlist` of lines of match strings. After that, most of the work is done.

The subsequent `for` loop tests just `E030018B13Rik` to see if it is one of the keys of the new `%ASlist` and prints an appropriate message

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ASlist = (
    'HSPA5   BIP FLJ26106    GRP78   MIF2',
    'NDUFA5  B13 CI-13KD-B   DKFZp781K1356   FLJ12147    NUFM    UQOR13',
    'ACAN    AGC1    AGCAN   CSPG1   CSPGCP  MSK16   SEDK',
);

my %ASlist = map { $_ => 1 } map /\S+/g, @ASlist;

for (qw/ E030018B13Rik /) {
  printf "%s %s\n", $_, $ASlist{$_} ? 'matches' : 'doesn\'t match';
}
```

**output**

```
E030018B13Rik doesn't match
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `B13` as the regular expression. As none of the characters has a special meaning, any string containing the substring `B13` matches the expression.

```
E030018B13Rik
       ^^^
```

If you want the expression to match the whole string, use anchors:

```
if ($name =~m/^$synonyms[$i]$/) {
```

Or, use `index` or `eq` to detect substrings (or identical strings, respectively), as your input doesn't seem to use any features of regular expressions.

Comment: I lose many potential matches using those exact anchors, but I am seeing that I can modify the regex to be case insensitive...

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to compare two strings, you can simply use eq:

```
if ( $name eq $synonyms[$i] ){
```